# What is an "alpha answer"?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations

> It may seem a bit odd to return a number for the day of the week, so there’s a function
>   to return the day as its name. The `DAYNAME` function works like `DAYOFWEEK` or
>   `WEEKDAY` but returns a string with the name instead, as shown in Example 8-12.
>   As you can see, **an alpha answer** returns:
>
> ```
> +-----------------------+
> | DAYNAME('1964-10-12') |
> +-----------------------+
> | Monday                |
> +-----------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> <sub>Source: [*Learning PHP & MySQL: Step-by-Step Guide to Creating Database-Driven Web Sites,* by Michele E. Davis, Jon A. Phillips](http://books.google.com/books?id=IpuT0GxHvAkC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=%22It+may+seem+a+bit+odd+to+return+a+number+for+the+day+of+the+week,+so+there%E2%80%99s+a+function+to+return+the+day+as+its+name.%22&source=bl&ots=87r4uy55BE&sig=qPhF4E_0m2ZCmjGlr_mHaL9g3mw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hwjtU5XCF8SXyASkh4DoBA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22It%20may%20seem%20a%20bit%20odd%20to%20return%20a%20number%20for%20the%20day%20of%20the%20week%2C%20so%20there%E2%80%99s%20a%20function%20to%20return%20the%20day%20as%20its%20name.%22&f=false)</sub>

What does *an alpha answer* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, *alpha* is an abbreviation for *alphabetic*. The passage is telling us that the `DAYNAME` function returns an value (*answer*) consisting only of letters (*alpha*), rather than a numerical indicator, which is what `DAYOFWEEK` and `WEEKDAY` return.

The use of the term *alpha answer* is not standard English at all. Even in the realm of programming jargon, it's not correct. Though we can determine the meaning from the context, *alpha* by itself is ambiguous as an abbreviation. It can mean either *alphabetic* or *alphanumeric*, both of which are frequently used when talking about strings. Also, *answer* is the wrong word (even colloquially) for referring to the result yielded by a function. The correct term is *return value* (often shortened to just *value*).

In addition to misusing the terms, the sentence containing *an alpha answer* is semantically wrong. The *answer* is what's returned, but it's being used as the subject of the sentence when it should be an object. As written, the sentence means the *answer* is what's doing the returning. This is wrong because the return value is just a value; it doesn't do anything. It's the *function* that returns something.

Here's how it should be written:

> As you can see, the function returns an alphabetic value:

Answer (score 1):

"Alpha" is an abbreviation for *alphabetic*. That sentence could have been written, "As you can see, a *string* returns."

Comment: I think it's worth making the point that OP's example is not in the least "idiomatic". Personally, I'd go so far as to say it's ***ignorant/incorrect***, but that's just me.

Comment: Because this is a question about technical programming jargon, I feel compelled to point out that it's wrong to claim that *alpha* means the same as *string*. A string may contain *any* characters, not just alphabetic letters. Indeed, in the example, `'1964-10-12'` is a string but definitely not *alpha*.

Comment: Since we're going to be pedantic, a string's a superset of alpha characters. The returned valued is a string. There's no claim that they are equivalent. Pointing out how it could also have been written was an attempt to show this is pretty poor documentation without writing a page on the topic - and linking it back to programming terminology. Hell, since we're talking MySQL, varchar is likely even better.